# Python Pandas: multi-index unstack taking forever

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've read a DataFrame from a .csv file with the following columns:

```
columns = ['Year', 'month', 'column1', 'column2','column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7', 'column8','Value']
```

The dataframe has 116408 rows but after `df = df.drop_duplicates()` it now has 98829 (I don't know why it had duplicates in the first place)

I need to unstack it like this:

```
                         1              2              3              ....
                         2016 2017 2018 2016 2017 2018 2016 2017 2018 .... 
column1 column2 .......  
     a1      a2    ...     24   12   20   22   15   21   12   11   13  ...
     b1      b2    ...     18   11   21   21   11   31   14   41   14  ...
```

So far, I've tried:

```
df = df.set_index(columns[:-1], append=True)
df = df.unstack(level=[0,1])
```

But this takes forever. (If I remove the `append` a get this error: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`)

Does anyone have another option or any idea why it's taking so long?
I haven't seen the result nor any error.

Comment: Maybe `df.to_dict(10)` and paste the output here, so we can reproduce your data?

Comment: I've got ideas.  But, I'm guessing.  And I don't want to spend my time guessing.  You can solve that problem by providing sample data.  The benefit to you would be that you improve your chances of getting a higher volume of quality answers.

Comment: We can not help you ...until seeing the data..

Comment: I couldn't show the data, my computer crashed, but when I got back Alexander's answer worked, kind of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are unstacking the wrong levels.  Because you have `append=True` when you set the index, the first value in your new index is whatever it was (you don't indicate what this index value is, so I am just assuming a continuous range starting at zero).  The next two levels would then be `Year` and `month`.

So, try this to get your desired output:

```
df.unstack(level=[1, 2])
```

---

```
np.random.seed(0)
columns = ['Year', 'month', 'column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6', 'column7', 'column8','Value']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(99, 11), columns=columns)
df.loc[:, 'Year'] = [2016, 2017, 2018] * 33
df.loc[:, 'month'] = [1, 2, 3] * 33

>>> df.set_index(columns[:-1], append=True).unstack(level=[1,2]).head()
                                                                                      Value  \
Year                                                                                   2016   
month                                                                                     1   
  column1   column2   column3   column4   column5   column6   column7   column8               
0  0.978738  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  0.410599  0.144044   
1  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674  1.494079 -0.205158  0.313068 -0.854096 -2.552990       NaN   
2  2.269755 -1.454366  0.045759 -0.187184  1.532779  1.469359  0.154947  0.378163       NaN   
3  0.156349  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303 -1.048553 -1.420018 -1.706270  1.950775   
4 -1.252795  0.777490 -1.613898 -0.212740 -0.895467  0.386902 -0.510805 -1.180632       NaN   

                                                                                             \
Year                                                                                   2017   
month                                                                                     2   
  column1   column2   column3   column4   column5   column6   column7   column8               
0  0.978738  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  0.410599       NaN   
1  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674  1.494079 -0.205158  0.313068 -0.854096 -2.552990  0.653619   
2  2.269755 -1.454366  0.045759 -0.187184  1.532779  1.469359  0.154947  0.378163       NaN   
3  0.156349  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303 -1.048553 -1.420018 -1.706270       NaN   
4 -1.252795  0.777490 -1.613898 -0.212740 -0.895467  0.386902 -0.510805 -1.180632 -0.028182   


Year                                                                                   2018  
month                                                                                     3  
  column1   column2   column3   column4   column5   column6   column7   column8              
0  0.978738  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  0.410599       NaN  
1  0.121675  0.443863  0.333674  1.494079 -0.205158  0.313068 -0.854096 -2.552990       NaN  
2  2.269755 -1.454366  0.045759 -0.187184  1.532779  1.469359  0.154947  0.378163 -0.887786  
3  0.156349  1.230291  1.202380 -0.387327 -0.302303 -1.048553 -1.420018 -1.706270       NaN  
4 -1.252795  0.777490 -1.613898 -0.212740 -0.895467  0.386902 -0.510805 -1.180632       NaN
```

Comment: The operative word here is guessing. @Rosa Alejandra, if you say "this doesn't work :(", then you should understand that's because you didn't make your problem statement clear enough, with data, so you forced users to take shots in the dark.